# Is it safe to pass array as argument to function ? As the third party function can explore other elements than the one they meant for

Tags: c++

```
int tenTimes(int n) {
      return 10*n;
}

void tenTimesVector3(int vector[3]) {
      vector[0] = tenTimes(vector[0]);
      vector[1] = tenTimes(vector[1]);
      vector[2] = tenTimes(vector[2]);   
}
```

Here we are passing one element to the function but using that they are accessing all elements.

Comment: What is the question? This code doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Varun, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read through our guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Currently I am failing to understand what your question means... it would help if you could clarify it. Thanks!

Comment: It will only work when your function signature of `tenTimesVector` is `void tenTimesVector3(int *vector)`.

Comment: @yadhu No, it just needs `tenTimes()` to have an `int` return type. The function signature is (was) fine.

Comment: @Galik - With all due respect, you didn't "put the question back". The OP's code is illustrative. The question is in the title, and pretty clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you worry about the mutability of your buffer, then in general yes, it's not "safe" to pass a non-const reference to your buffer into a function. As you noted, the function can modify any array element.

If the function is const correct (it accepts a const reference or pointer), then you can be fairly certain it won't modify your array by accident. A compiler will catch any attempt at modification. Of course, the function can cast away the const and do nasty things, `const` here will offer some protection from Murphy, not from Machiavelli.

The only way to be absolutely positive a function won't modify your data is to not let it reference it. If you are genuinely concerned, you can just pass it a copy:

```
std::vector<int> data_we_want_to_keep(3);
// ...
std::vector<int> copy_of_data = data_we_want_to_keep;
tenTimesVector3(copy_of_data.data());
```

Now the function will not be able to modify `data_we_want_to_keep` itself, despite needing access to whatever values in that buffer.

Quite often though, code is written to be well behaved. If a function accepts a const reference or pointer to your data, you can be reasonably assured it will only read it.

Comment: I am still looking for the _definite textbook compilation_ of the Stack Overflow questions and answers. Remember that the _documentation_ project failed badly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Beg your pardon?

Comment: You have my pardon. Though I think we don't need to answer everything basic like that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - And you have my permission to hold that opinion. If you find a duplicate for this conceptual question, do let me know.

Comment: Fair point you have.